# Problem with subtracting columns from same table with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have one table on which i'm trying to subtruct two columns. In that regard I'm using two subqueries, each subquery select data by different criteria.

Here is [example of my table with data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a85356/5) and query which i'm executing and trying to get this result:

```
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| SifraProizvoda| rezultat    | BrojRacuna  |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| 509001600     | 16000       | 9/PP1       |
| 509001800     | 21989       | 10/PP1      |
| 509001700     | 9000        | 10/PP1      |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
```

But somehow i get this:

```
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| SifraProizvoda| rezultat    | BrojRacuna  |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| 509001300     | 1000        | 9/PP1       |
| 509001300     | 4000        | 9/PP1       |
| 509001600     | 16000       | 9/PP1       |
| 509001800     | 21989       | 10/PP1      |
| 509001700     | 9000        | 10/PP1      |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Which is not correct. For product 509001300 i should have 0 as result.

How to properly join two subqueries on the same table?

Table definion and insert data:

```
CREATE TABLE `odobrenja` (
    `BrojOdobrenja` VARCHAR(50),
    `SifraProizvoda` VARCHAR(50),
    `OdobrenoKOM` INT(11),
    `IzvezenoKOM` INT(11),
    `UvezenoGPKOM` INT(11),
    `PS` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `BrojRacuna` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `GodinaRN` SMALLINT(6),
    `BrojDeklaracije` VARCHAR(50),
    `DatumIsteka` DATE,
    `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `DVRn` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `IDVezaRNIzvoz` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `IDRacun` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
);

INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001300', 0, 5000, 0, 2, '9/PP1/7', 2022, '12121212', NULL, 2429, '2022-03-20 00:00:00', 0, 93);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001600', 0, 20000, 0, 2, '9/PP1/7', 2022, '12121212', NULL, 2430, '2022-03-20 00:00:00', 0, 93);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001800', 0, 22000, 0, 2, '10/PP1/7', 2022, '4343434', NULL, 2431, '2022-03-20 00:00:00', 0, 94);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001700', 0, 14000, 0, 2, '10/PP1/7', 2022, '4343434', NULL, 2432, '2022-03-20 00:00:00', 0, 94);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001300', 0, 0, 4000, 3, '9/2022', 2022, '', NULL, 2439, '2022-03-20 00:00:00', 93, 0);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001600', 0, 0, 4000, 3, '9/2022', 2022, '', NULL, 2440, '2022-03-20 00:00:00', 93, 0);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001800', 0, 0, 11, 3, '9/2022', 2022, '', NULL, 2441, '2022-03-20 00:00:00', 94, 0);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001300', 0, 1000, 0, 2, '11/PP1/7', 2022, '2323', NULL, 2444, '2022-03-20 00:00:00', 0, 95);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001300', 0, 1000, 0, 2, '12/PP1/7', 2022, 'fdfd', NULL, 2447, '2022-03-25 00:00:00', 0, 96);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001700', 0, 5000, 0, 2, '12/PP1/7', 2022, 'fdfd', NULL, 2449, '2022-03-25 00:00:00', 0, 96);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001300', 0, 0, 1000, 3, '10/2022', 2022, '', NULL, 2452, '2022-03-26 00:00:00', 93, 0);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001700', 0, 0, 5000, 3, '11/2022', 2022, '', NULL, 2453, '2022-03-26 00:00:00', 94, 0);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001300', 0, 0, 1000, 3, '11/2022', 2022, '', NULL, 2454, '2022-03-26 00:00:00', 95, 0);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001300', 0, 0, 1000, 3, '11/2022', 2022, '', NULL, 2455, '2022-03-26 00:00:00', 96, 0);
INSERT INTO `odobrenja` (`BrojOdobrenja`, `SifraProizvoda`, `OdobrenoKOM`, `IzvezenoKOM`, `UvezenoGPKOM`, `PS`, `BrojRacuna`, `GodinaRN`, `BrojDeklaracije`, `DatumIsteka`, `ID`, `DVRn`, `IDVezaRNIzvoz`, `IDRacun`) VALUES ('20032022-1951', '509001700', 0, 0, 5000, 3, '11/2022', 2022, '', NULL, 2456, '2022-03-26 00:00:00', 96, 0);
```

query:

```
SELECT t1.SifraProizvoda, 
(COALESCE(t1.IzvezenoKOM, 0) - COALESCE(t2.UvezenoGPKOM, 0)) AS rezultat, t1.BrojRacuna
FROM  
(
   SELECT odobrenja.BrojOdobrenja, 
   odobrenja.SifraProizvoda, 
   odobrenja.IzvezenoKOM, 
   odobrenja.BrojRacuna, 
   odobrenja.IDracun 
   FROM odobrenja WHERE odobrenja.BrojOdobrenja = '20032022-1951' AND odobrenja.PS = 2) AS t1
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT 
   odobrenja.BrojOdobrenja, 
   odobrenja.SifraProizvoda, 
   odobrenja.UvezenoGPKOM AS UvezenoGPKOM, 
   odobrenja.BrojRacuna, odobrenja.IDVezaRNIzvoz 
   FROM odobrenja WHERE odobrenja.BrojOdobrenja = '20032022-1951' AND odobrenja.PS = 3) AS t2
ON t1.SifraProizvoda = t2.SifraProizvoda  and t1.IDracun = t2.IDVezaRNIzvoz  
HAVING rezultat > 0
```

Comment: Please share your query and the expected result based on the provided sample data.

Comment: Share what are you trying to accomplish and why the expected result is not correct.

Comment: @JorgeCampos it's alreday there in 2nd sentence, but here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a85356/5

Comment: @ErgestBasha http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a85356/5

Comment: @Josef your query is working fine. I need to understand why rezultat equal to 1000 and 4000  should be excluded ?

Comment: Yeah I saw the fiddle though It is still preferable to have the sql here as fiddle is an external site and your query can be lost.

Comment: @ErgestBasha when you go by hand you will see than for 509001300 subtruction gives 0. On left side you have totally 7000 and on right side also 7000 which gives result 0.

Comment: @JorgeCampos i just modified post with complete CRUD

Comment: Tip 1: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read. (And to write.) Scrolling sideways is a pain.

Comment: Tip 2: Save some typing, make the query easier to read - use table aliases.